# Workflow failing to update list item

Tags: 2010, workflow, infopath, updatelistitems

I have a workflow that takes the `Account Id` inserted from an InfoPath form and updates a People column field with it. It will usually work as expected right after I publish the workflow but sequential attempts fail. I can see the value from the `Account Id` column coming through right everytime.

Usually I get this message in the log if it fails:

```
The item is currently locked for editing. Waiting for item to be checked in or for the lock to be released.
```

Versioning is turned off for this form library and I can't find anything significant in the ULS logs. I've also reproduced this issue on 2 servers.

Using the `Pause for duration` action doesn't help either. Has anyone experienced this issue and have a solution?

Comment: could you try using the wait for document to be unlocked by document editor action instead of the pause and see if that helps?

Comment: That worked like a charm in my dev env. I'm waiting on the staging to release. it's been waiting for a while now tho...

Comment: It's been waiting for over 10 mins now! That's too long right?

Comment: Seems like that's too long

Comment: dev is working like a charm... this is weird